# openGL window crash

Tags: opengl, visual-c++-6

i am working on openGL in Vc6
every time i run the following simple code output **window crashes**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
//#include <gl/glaux.h>

void display(void)
{

    glColor3f(255.0f,255.0f,255.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,5.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(5.0f,5.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(5.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

 void init(void)
 {
        glViewport(0,0,400,400);
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0,4/3,4.0,1000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gluLookAt(2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    init();
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(400,400);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("Trial");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

i don't know what is going wrong any boby please help

Comment: Why on earth are you still using VC6?

Comment: and i also included proper headers 'glut.h' 'gluax.h'

Comment: Where is it crashing? On what exact line?

Comment: In addition to calling functions in the wrong order, it looks like you've requested a double-buffering context, but I don't see any call to swap the buffers.

Answer (score 5):

You are using OpenGL functions before you have an OpenGL context (which is a requirement to call any GL functions at all). The context is created by `glutCreateWindow`, but your first call to GL functions happens in `init()`. To fix this, you could move your `init()` call right below the `glutCreateWindow` call.